# How to get a list of AWS EIP addresses from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, eip

I have a use case where I would like to run a script using all existing elastic IP addresses in a specific VPC.

Any thoughts on the best way to generate that list?

I've been looking through the AWS CLI documentation and can't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The command you are looking for](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-addresses.html) (which is certainly difficult to find due to the unintuitive name) is:

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses
```

Answer (score 17):

@Mark's answer is correct. I am just extrapolating the exact command to list the elastic ip's.

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --region us-east-1 --query 'Addresses[*].PublicIp'
```

Comment: The addition is really helpful!